# String conversion overhead

Tags: python-2.7

This may sound like a stupid question, but I was wondering if python's `str()`method causes overhead if the input itself is a string?

e.g. I am using `redis.get()` method to get a value from redis, and I don't know the type beforehand, so I call the `str()` method on the return value. 
I could put it in an if-else block and call `str()` on returned value only if it is not already string type, but is such mechanism already implemented inside `str()` implementation?

Comment: `str` special-cases strings and doesn't create a duplicate, but there will still be overhead in calling it. I doubt it would be a problem, though; ignore it unless there's a performance problem and profiling suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str()` is a bit faster if you need to convert:

```
a = 'a'
b = 1

%timeit x = str(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 284 ns per loop

%%timeit
if isinstance(a, str):
    x = a
else:
    x = str(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 274 ns per loop

%timeit str(b)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 366 ns per loop

%%timeit
if isinstance(b, str):
    x = b
else:
    x = str(b)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 636 ns per loop
```

and much more elegant and shorter. So go with `str()`.